# TypeScript File upload error - Type 'File' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, upload

This is my `PlayerInterface`

```
interface playerInterface {
    id?: string,
    _id?: null,
    name: string
    club: string,
    image?: string,
    important: boolean
}
```

This is my `useState` hook:

```
const [player, setPlayer] = useState<PlayerInterface>({ id: '', name: '', club: '', important: false, image: '' })
```

And this is my `handleFileUpload`:

```
const handleFileUpload = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setPlayer({ ...player, image: e.target.files![0] })
}
```

Right now, in `handleFileUpload`, the `image` is underlined, with the error saying `Type 'File' is not assignable to type 'string'`

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Based on your edit to `playerInterface`, you are trying to assign a `File` ( `e.target.files![0]`) to a `string` variable. Try changing playerInterface to a File type, or using a [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) to store it as a data string.

Without knowing what database you are using, it is difficult to say exactly what the problem is, but it is likely you will need to convert the binary/Base64 string representation of the uploaded file back into its original format in order to store it as a File. However, from my experience, I would suggest storing the file as the string representation, and only converting to the image/file representation when it is actually required (i.e. on rendering in your front end).

Comment: I use MongoDB. But in the frontend I cannot seem to fix the error in my OP