# How to initialize useState in TypeScript using union?

Tags: typescript

My `PlayerInterface`

```
interface playerInterface {
    id?: string,
    _id?: null,
    name: string
    club: string,
    image?: File | object,
    important: boolean
}
```

My `useState`:

```
const [player, setPlayer] = useState<PlayerInterface>({ name: '', club: '', important: false, image: '' })
```

As you can see, `name` and `club` are easy because they are string, and `important` too, as it is only a boolean, so I can just simply type `club: ''` or `important: false`.

But what about `image`? It has to be either `File` or `object`. I tried doing `image: (File | object)` and it does not work. What is the right syntax here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize it with either a File or an object.

This would work:

```
const [player, setPlayer] = useState<PlayerInterface>({ name: '', club: '', important: false, image: {} })
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried doing that but the `image` in my `handleFileUpload` is still giving me an error. When you have time please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74036105/typescript-file-upload-error-type-file-is-not-assignable-to-type-string/74036180#74036180

Comment: In your `handleFileUpload` you have to check if the value you are assigning to image is of the `File` type (use an if statement).

Comment: ```
const file = e.target.files![0]
        if(typeof file === File) {

        setPlayer({ ...player, image: e.target.files![0] })
    }
```

And I got this error now: `This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and '{ new (fileBits: BlobPart[], fileName: string, options?: FilePropertyBag | undefined): File; prototype: File; }' have no overlap`